# datagrid filter interfering with for loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, datagridview, filter

Following code works great, but does not work (index out of range) if I set a filter to the datagridview. The filter is set through the filter of a binding source. (see below)

```
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Contains(TextBox2.Text) And DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString.Contains(TextBox3.Text) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString.Replace(TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text)
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red

        End If

    Next
```

Filter:

```
BindingSource1.Filter = "[orig] like '*" & TextBox1.Text & "*' or [ita] like '*" & TextBox1.Text & "*'"
```

Any Idea why and how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the "filter"? If the above code is working as you said, we cannot guess where the problem is.

Comment: youre right.. updated with the filter. thanks